# ¿Cómo sumar valores que no estaban cargados en el DOM?

Tags: javascript

Quiero hacer un carrito de compras y que cada vez que agregue un producto actualice el total, todos los productos cuestan 100 pesos, el código de la función es el siguiente, y el resultado es que en la consola solo deja el 100 y antes el numero de veces que le dí click a agregar al carrito

```
function enviarProducto(pro){
    const div = document.createElement('div');
     div.innerHTML = `
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <img src="${pro.imagen}" class="imagen-producto-carrito">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class ="col ml-4"><h4 class="titulo-producto-carrito">${pro.titulo}</h4></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                   <h4>Precio: <span class="precio-producto-carrito  text-aling-center">${pro.precio}</span></h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class ="col"><p class="texto-producto-carrito">${pro.descripcion}</p></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class ="col"><button id="${pro.id}" class="boton-eliminar-carrito btn btn-danger btn-block">Eliminar del carrito</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


     `;
     body.appendChild(div);
     guardarProductoLS(pro);
     let total = 0;
     let precio = parseInt(pro.precio);
     total = precio + total;
     console.log(total);
}
```

Comment: Uh... como que falta una parte de la pregunta

Comment: La pregunta es porque no suma los valores que mando a la consola, solo pone el 100 del precio y antes el numero de veces que le he dado click agregar al carrito

Comment: Ya veo... es que no tiene mucho que ver el título, me confundí

Comment: Tienes razón, iba a cambiar el título pero lo olvidé, gracias por intentar ayudarme .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No está sumando los valores porque cada que ves que llamas a la función `enviarProducto`
estás poniendo la variable `total` en 0.

```
function enviarProducto(pro) {
  ...
  let total = 0; // no debe ir aca
  ...
}
```

Lo que debes hacer es mover la variable `total` afuera de la función, por ejemplo así:

```
let total = 0; // por ejemplo aca podrías ponerla

function enviarProducto(pro) {
  ...
  /* let total = 0; (esto se movio afuera de la función) */
  ...
}
```

Comment: Fue un error muy tonto de mi parte, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: No te preocupes amigo, todos nos equivocamos. Saludos!